# Annoying class hierarchy with mixed attributes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I've created `ColorBlock` and `ImageBlock` classes subclassing from abstract `Block` class.
`Block` implements size and position and has an abstract method `draw()`.
`ColorBlock` implements `color` attribute and draws itself as a color square.
`ImageBlock` implements `image` attribute and draws itself as a square with an image inside it.

Now I want to make the blocks movable, but I also want to keep the unmovable blocks.
Basically I would have to create `MovableColorBlock` and `MovableImageBlock`, and they both implement the exact same moving action.
The class hierarchy would be like this:

```
Block
|--ColorBlock
|----MovableColorBlock
|--ImageBlock
|----MovableImageBlock
```

And as you see, I'm implementing the moving action twice.
An other way to implement this would be something like:

```
Block
|--ColorBlock
|--ImageBlock
|--MovableBlock (abstract)
|----MovableColorBlock
|----MovableImageBlock
```

Now I'm implementing the moving only once, but `Color` and `Image` twice.
Is there an easy solution, or will I need duplicate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that pretty much every graphics/physics engine experiences.

I would recommend having Movable block be a subclass of Block and having Color and Image block derive from that. After all, a non-moving block is just a moving block with no velocity.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for, but tbh this is the only sane answer so far :P

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

For your particular case, you could imagine `MovableBlock` as a Decorator to Block, which could be applied to `ColorBlock` and `ImageBlock` (which would be ConcreteComponents to the Component `Block`).

Here's an alternate [example](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) - look at the `ScrollableWindow` description, which might make it easier to see the analogy with your example.

Comment: This too is a working solution, but hard to maintain and doesn't really work with C++'s class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a `Movable` interface (pure virtual class) that declares methods for moving, and derive subclasses that implement those methods:

```
Block                 Movable
  |                     |
  +-ColorBlock----------+-MovableColorBlock
  |                     |
  +-ImageBlock----------+-MovableImageBlock
```

**Edit**

Yeah, if the `move()` method really is the same between the subclasses, then this isn't what you want.

It sounds like the `move()` operation is orthagonal to the `draw()` operation, which to me suggests an aggregation instead of a subclass.  So let's take a slight left turn here.

A `Block` has a position; perhaps the positional parameter could be what's movable or not:

```
class Position 
{
  public:

  Position( int x, int y ) : m_x(x), m_y(y) { }
  virtual ~Position() {}

  int getX() const { return m_x; }
  int getY() const { return m_y; }

  virtual bool movable() const { return false; }

  protected:

  int m_x;
  int m_y;
};

class MovablePosition : public Position
{
  public:

  MovablePosition( int x, int y ) : Position( x, y ) {}
  virtual ~MovablePosition() {}

  void move( int newX, int newY ) { m_x = newX; m_y = newY; }

  virtual bool movable() const { return true; }
};
```

Then your base `Block` class takes a `Position` as a parameter:

```
class Block 
{
  public: 

  Block( Position *p ) : m_pos( p ) {}
  virtual ~Block() {}

  virtual void draw() = 0;

  Position *getPos() const { return m_pos; }

  protected:

  Position *m_pos;
};
```

Then if you want to move a `Block` subclass instance, you'd first check the `movable()` method:

```
if ( myColorBlock.getPos()->movable() )
{
  MovablePosition *p = myColorBlock.getPos();
  p->move( newX, newY );
  myColorBlock.draw();
}
```

No need to create redundant `MovableXxxBlock` classes, no repetition of code.  Under this scheme, a block's movability is established at runtime, not compile time; that may or may not be compatible with your goals.

Comment: Doesn't really satisfy me, interfaces are hardly ever a proper solution and this is one of those cases where it seems really wrong. This doesn't really create a proper hierarchy tree, you can't (well, you can do anything in programming, but you shouldn't) just implement all functionality with interfaces.

Comment: It's a lot better now, I'll give it a try later on today when I get home. Might still not be what I'm looking for, but I'll give it a thought later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `MovableColorBlock` and `MovableImageBlock` friend classes of 'MoveableBlock' and inherit from their respective "non-moving" `Block` classes.  You'll still have the two extra classes but the `friend` declaration will let them access the moving implementation in `MoveableBlock`